# Mint 19 - Pidgin IM - Error while launching: libpurple.so.0: cannot open shared object file

Tags: shared-library, pidgin

System: Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon 64-bit, based on Ubuntu 18.04.

Pidgin: Built from source, version 2.13.0.

---

Pidgin would not launch from the GUI, so I tried it from terminal if I can see any error and here it is:

> ```
> pidgin: error while loading shared libraries: libpurple.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I located the library and created symlinks to it like so:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpurple.so /usr/lib/
```

and

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpurple.so.0 /usr/lib/
```

The problem seems to be resolved.

Comment: Better idea is set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it will not affect other filesystem directory, making uninstallation easier.

Comment: @神秘德里克 Feel free to add your own answer ;)